# WordPress RSS feed - filter RSS content by custom field value

Tags: filters, hooks, rss

I can have the RSS feed url like:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/?post_type=job_listing&job_cat=value#1&job_type=value#2&geo_country=value#3&feed=rss2
```

`job_cat` & `job_type` are taxonomies for the `job_listing` post type and they are considered / generated in the RSS feeds correctly.

Recently I've added a custom field parameter in te RSS feed url's called `geo_country`. If a value is returned for this in the RSS feed url (not empty), then the RSS content should be filtered also by the custom field's value. Which is not happening currently, of course.

Using the `Jobbroller` theme, but I haven't found in them any RSS related code, function(s).

Is there any way to write a hook in the described scenario?

Comment: What kind of values does `geo_country` take?

Comment: Only alpa-numeric values :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to add `geo_country` as an extra query variable with:

```
/**
 * Add the 'geo_country' as a public query variable
 *
 * @param array $query_vars
 * @return array $query_vars
 */ 
function my_query_vars( $query_vars ) 
{
    $query_vars[] = 'geo_country';
    return $query_vars;
}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'my_query_vars' );
```

and then setup a `pre_get_posts` hook to filter your feed according to the `geo_country` value:

```
/**
 * Filter the feed by the 'geo_country' meta key 
 *
 * @param WP_Query object $query
 * @return void 
 */ 
function my_pre_get_posts( $query ) 
{
    // only for feeds
    if( $query->is_feed && $query->is_main_query() ) 
    {
        // check if the geo_country variable is set 
        if( isset( $query->query_vars['geo_country'] ) 
                && ! empty( $query->query_vars['geo_country'] ) )
        {

            // if you only want to allow 'alpha-numerics':
            $geo_country =  preg_replace( "/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $query->query_vars['geo_country'] ); 

            // set up the meta query for geo_country
            $query->set( 'meta_key', 'geo_country' );
            $query->set( 'meta_value', $geo_country );
        }

    } 
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts' );
```

I assume `geo_country` takes only alpha-numeric values `(a-z,A-Z,0-9)`, just let me know if that's not the case.

This works on my install with the *Twenty Twelve* theme.

Comment: Thanks you for your help! It seems to work like a charm! Wonderful. So first a public query variable must be built and then filter the `pre_get_posts`. Admirable :)

Comment: It says that I can award the bounty in 12 hours. Please remind me kindly if I forget to award you in max 24 hours.

Comment: Thanks, I'm happy to hear it solves your problem, cheers.

Comment: One tiny little thing. It isn't your fault of course, but it isn't working for countries that are 2 words (I.e. United Kingdom or United States). Perhaps something to so with the space? What it is recommended on such cases?

Comment: In general I would recommend using lower case initials for the `geo_country` url parameter, like `uk, us, fr, ...` etc if that's possible for you. Otherwise you should check the values with `var_dump( $query->query_vars['geo_country'] );` before the `preg_replace` to figure out what other characters to allow (other than `a-zA-Z0-9`).

Comment: I have the URL like this `geo_country=United+Kingdom` after sending the value, but in RSS it is like `geo_country=United Kingdom`

Comment: You can try `"/[^ a-zA-Z0-9]/"` to allow spaces.

Comment: Thanks, I have removed totally the `preg_replace` and it works fine. :)

Comment: ok ;-) ps: it's always good to have some control over the user input, this [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data) and [this one](http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation), for example, are useful on that matter.